# Update at MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I'm trying to update a user email at MongoDB, but I need to verify previously if this e-mail does not exist yet. In my Schema, I have:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true  }
});
```

And in my controller:

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const entries = Object.keys(req.body);
  const updates = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i += 1) {
    updates[entries[i]] = Object.values(req.body)[i];
  }

  const userId = req.body._id ? req.body._id : req.userId;
  User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $set: updates }).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed!" });
      return;
    }
    if (data.n === 0) {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "Not Found!" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Success!" });
  });
      
};
```

It's working well, but if I enter an email already used, I get to update.
How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `unique: true` in your schema you can update the value and only will return `success` if it is not duplicated.

By the way, if you want to return a message error specific if the `email` exists you can check if the error is the code `11000`.

Something like this:

```
User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $set: updates }).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if(err.code === 11000){
         return res.status(400).send({ message: "Uniques values already exists"});
      } else {
         return res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed!" });
      }
    }
    if (data.n === 0) {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "Not Found!" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Success!" });
  });
```

Comment: It wasn't working, but now it's working... A mystery code! Thanks a bunch!!